# Configurable blocking and non-blocking requests in NIO

Tags: java, nio

I am planning to use java NIO for my project, but one of my requirement is to keep the requests configurable, i.e. the client can select the request to be: 1. blocking, 2. non blocking.

So, is it possible to use NIO in a sync. way?

There is an option on the client code when creating the channel:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
```

But, I get this error when I make it as true.

[This](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/src/NioClient.java) is the client code I am using from [this tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html).

```
java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:172)
    at java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel.register(SelectableChannel.java:254)
    at com.dds.client.DDSClient.run(DDSClient.java:77)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadocs for [`register(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#register%28java.nio.channels.Selector,%20int%29) state that if you call the method on a channel that is in blocking mode, that exception *will* be thrown.  A selector can only handle a non-blocking channel.

You need to change your code to use a blocking operations (e.g. `read` or `write`) rather than `register` and `select` when you want blocking semantics.

Comment: I am new to NIO, any pointers to the code modification in read()/write() (I think the changes will only be in write()) on client code?

Comment: @zengr: The read() and write() calls don't change, the code around them does. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use select() on a blocking channel, as the Javadocs say. You more or less have to use the model of a thread per channel.

What is the reason for this strange requirement?

Comment: Arguably it's NIO that has "strange requirements".  The corresponding POSIX functions do not have this restriction: It's perfectly legal to call `select()` on a blocking socket.

Comment: @finnw: I'm referring to the strange requirement that the client chooses the blocking mode. The Windows APIs they are using have the same requirement that select() needs non-blocking mode.

Comment: Reason: I need to provide an API to the client side, where if the data is not very critical then it should be in a non-blocking manner (async) and if the data to be persisted is very critical, then it should be in blocking manner and the client should get an ACK whether the data has been saved or not. Am I understanding NIO correctly? same analogy of: MDB vs Session?

Comment: @zengr: So your requirement is actually for *critical* vs. *non-critical.* It is highly questionable that non-critical = non-blocking and that critical = blocking. I could make an argument at least as good for the other way round. Don't define the implementation before you've understood the requirements and their *real* implications. The requirement can be met it several ways: for example, by an adjustable *client-side* timeout with exactly the same implementation at the server end. I have no idea what 'MDB vs Session' has to do with it.